# Extract data from JSON from an API with Python

Tags: python, json, exception

The data under consideration is coming from an API, which means that it's highly inconsistent- sometimes it pulls unexpected content, sometimes it pulls nothing, etc.

What I'm interested in is the data associated with [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:DE) for each record.

The data (when it doesn't encounter an error) generally looks something like this:

```
{"countryCode": "GB", "adminCode1": "ENG", "countryName": "United Kingdom", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "ENG"}], "adminName1": "England"}
{"countryCode": "GB", "adminCode1": "ENG", "countryName": "United Kingdom", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "ENG"}], "adminName1": "England"}
{"countryCode": "GB", "adminCode1": "ENG", "countryName": "United Kingdom", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "ENG"}], "adminName1": "England"}
{"countryCode": "GB", "adminCode1": "ENG", "countryName": "United Kingdom", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "ENG"}], "adminName1": "England"}
{"countryCode": "RO", "adminCode1": "10", "countryName": "Romania", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "10"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "B"}], "adminName1": "Bucure\u015fti"}
{"countryCode": "DE", "adminCode1": "07", "countryName": "Germany", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "07"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "NW"}], "adminName1": "North Rhine-Westphalia"}
{"countryCode": "DE", "adminCode1": "01", "countryName": "Germany", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "01"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "BW"}], "adminName1": "Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"}
{"countryCode": "DE", "adminCode1": "02", "countryName": "Germany", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "02"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "BY"}], "adminName1": "Bavaria"}
```

Let's take one record for example:

```
{"countryCode": "DE", "adminCode1": "01", "countryName": "Germany", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "01"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "BW"}], "adminName1": "Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"}
```

From this I'm interested to extract the `ISO 3166-2` representation, i.e. `DE-BW`.

I've been trying different ways of extracting this information with python, one attempt looked like this:

```
coord = response.get('codes', {}).get('type', {}).get('ISO3166-2', None)
```

another attempt looked like this:

```
print(json.dumps(response["codes"]["ISO3166-2"]))
```

However neither of those methods worked.

How can I take a record such as:

```
{"countryCode": "DE", "adminCode1": "01", "countryName": "Germany", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "01"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "BW"}], "adminName1": "Baden-W\u00fcrttemberg"}
```

and extract only `DE-BW` using python, while simultaneously controlling for instances that don't look exactly like that, for instance also extracting `GB-ENG` from:

```
{"countryCode": "GB", "adminCode1": "ENG", "countryName": "United Kingdom", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "ENG"}], "adminName1": "England"}
```

and of course not crashing if it gets something that doesn't look like either of those, i.e. exception handling.

---

**FULL FILE**

```
import json
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

# open up the output of 'data-processing.py'
with open('job-numbers-by-location.txt') as data_file:

    for line in data_file:
        identifier, name, coords, number_of_jobs = line.split("|")
        coords = coords[1:-1]
        lat, lng = coords.split(",")
        # print("lat: " + lat, "lng: " + lng)
        response = requests.get("http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivisionJSON?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&username=s.matthew.english").json()


        codes = response.get('codes', [])
        for code in codes:
            if code.get('type') == 'ISO3166-2':
                print('{}-{}'.format(response.get('countryCode', 'UNKNOWN'), code.get('code', 'UNKNOWN'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ISO3166-2' is dictionary value, not key

```
codes = response.get('codes', [])
for code in codes:
    if code.get('type') == 'ISO3166-2':
        print('{}-{}'.format(response.get('countryCode', 'UNKNOWN'), code.get('code', 'UNKNOWN')))
```

Comment: some of the records look like this `{"countryCode": "BE", "adminCode1": "VLG", "countryName": "Belgium", "distance": 0, "codes": [{"type": "FIPS10-4", "code": "13"}, {"type": "ISO3166-2", "code": "VLG"}], "adminName1": "Flanders"}`, and it seems to also be grabbing that `"FIPS10-4"` data, is there some modification that can be made to ignore those codes?

Comment: @s.matthew.english, I just tried with this record and it gives me BE-VLG

Comment: yeah true- it was my bad- I was putting it as part of a longer file. but do you have an idea about that `"FIPS10-4"`

Comment: For that particular record you provided there is no such problem, when I run the code.